# Passing data from laravel controller to Js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have problem about passing  data from controller to js, i am using this code for it ,i tried many things but nothing is  working  , am i doing something wrong ?

script:

```
var posts = {!! $post->toJson() !!};

alert(posts);
```

and my controller looks like this :

```
$post = Post::where('category',$id)->get();
```

but i am getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !" i really dont know why is there any solutions ?

Comment: Are you receiving data from $post?

Answer (score 2):

I always use this `posts = {!! json_encode($posts) !!};` and it works fine!

Comment: If this worked for you please check my answer as correct!

Comment: Maybe this `"posts = {!! json_encode($posts) !!};"` fix it for you!

Comment: nah same when  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !

Comment: writted it bad :S `posts = "{!! json_encode($posts) !!}";` notice the `"` before the `{!!` and after `!!}`. This is weird bc I faced this bug more times and i've always fixed this way.

Comment: it just alerts  string "{!! json_encode($posts) !!}" this

Comment: Wow. So much error here. Could you share how is $post object formed? Its properties with example

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
var posts = "{{ $post->toJson() }}";

alert(posts);
```

Comment: it alerts string